# How can I Inject javascript into Electron app?

Tags: javascript, electron

I am looking for ways to inject Javascript into the devtools console of an Electron app. I want to do this from another NodeJS script. Is there any library for this that can be of use, or how can I go about doing this?

I found a Python library called electron-inject that is able to do this, but I'd like to do it through NodeJS.

Comment: I suggest starting with the source code of electron-inject. it's all on GitHub for you to learn from!